# Replacing Double Quote by Single Quote

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `GridView` where I will display the data in my table. In my table, I have:

```
FIELD ITEM
=======
Fruit"s
Vegetable"s
```

That's how I saved it in my table. So in saving, I'm using `Replace("'", "\"");` but my problem is now how should I display it again in single quote.

This is how I saved it

```
SQLCMD = "INSERT INTO Table(fldItem) VALUES ('" + _strItem.Replace("'", "\"") + "')";
```

but when I tried to used it in code-behind:

```
string _qry = "SELECT Replace(fldItem,'"','''') FROM Table";
```

There's an error saying

> Too many characters in character literal

Comment: Okay, so you had a problem where you couldn't save single quotes into the database, probably because you were building your SQL using string-mangling rather than using parameters. You're now having problems with unmangling your data for display, but you're going to carry on down this route because...? Why not solve the original problem *correctly* and store the correct data?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Then how would i save single quote to sql? I tried that it has an error `"Unclose quotation mark after the character string"`

Comment: try `string _qry = "SELECT Replace(fldItem,\"\"\",\"'\") FROM Table";`

Comment: I can't give you specifics at this time since the only code you've shown us from the relevant place is `Replace("'", "\"")`. However, the hint is in my first comment - `parameters`.

Comment: It would be better using SQLCommand and DataParameter objects instead of rough string query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` with a backslash, `\"`.

So,

```
string _qry = "SELECT Replace(fldItem,'\"','''') FROM Table";
```

OR

```
string _qry = @"SELECT Replace(fldItem,'""','''') FROM Table";
```

**Test**

**[`Please check this`](http://ideone.com/KVjJZR)**